# Unwanted output on second pass using strcpy

Tags: c

I'm reading a book called "C programming Absolute Beginners Guide."
The following program uses some if loops and strcpy to store some character arrays provided by the user.  The first pass of strcpy works fine.  The second produces garbage.  I understand the array needs a \0 to end.  According to the book, strcpy does this automatically.  What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
main()
{
    int ctr, numMovies, rating, favRating, leastRating;
    char movieName[40], favorite[40], least[40];

    favRating = 0;
    leastRating = 0;

    do {
    printf("How many movies have you seen this year? ");
    scanf(" %d", &numMovies);

    if (numMovies < 1)
    {
        printf("No movies! How can you rank them?\nTry again\n\n");
    }

    } while (numMovies < 1 );

    for (ctr = 1; ctr <= numMovies; ctr++)
    {

    printf("\nWhat's the name of the movie? ");
    printf("(1-word titles only!) ");
    scanf(" %s", movieName);


    printf("On a scale of 1 to 10, what would ");
    printf("you rate it? ");
    scanf(" %d", &rating);

    if (rating > favRating)
    {

        strcpy(favorite, movieName);

        favRating = rating;
    }

            printf("%s", movieName);
    if (rating < leastRating)
    { 

        strcpy(least, movieName);
        leastRating = rating;
    }

}
printf("\nYour Favorite Movie was %s.\n", favorite);
printf("\nYour Least-favorite movie was %s.\n", least);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: "What am I missing?" 1) Proper indentation 2) Initialization of variables 3) Check of return values for `scanf` 4) Correct `main`definition 5) Protection against buffer overflow 6) Range check for `rating`

Comment: Use `int main(void)` — the return type has been required all of this millennium by Standard C.

Comment: Although it isn't a problem in this example, your `for (ctr = 1; ctr <= numMovies; ctr++)` loop is better written as `for (ctr = 0; ctr < numMovies; ctr++)` because C arrays are indexed from 0 and starting loops from 0 is more usually correct.

Comment: You should show what you mean by 'the second produces garbage'.  When do you see the garbage?  Is it simply that the least favourite movie is reported badly at the very end?  Or are you seeing a different problem.  Make sure arrays are initialized when necessary.  Please read about how to create an MCVE — [MCVE]. Input data, expected output, actual output are important parts of an MCVE, and are all missing.  (I note in passing that you don't verify that the rating is in the range 1..10 — maybe you should?  Maybe you should check that the user doesn't enter more than a dozen or two movies too.)

Comment: @xing I would say `leastRating=11`, otherwise no strcopy will be performed if all the movies are rated to 10 (although it won't make sens to pick the first movie as being the lowest rated).

Comment: This would be a better posting if you were do provide details about the actual program behavior, the input, the output, and what you expect. Also I suggest you check the documentation for the `scanf()` function and how it works and its behavior with various data types. It can be tricky sometimes as it is not always intuitive as to what `scanf()` is going to do with particular input.

Comment: @Amessihel: the first movie is both the favourite and least favourite; if there's only one movie, that remains true after the loop ends.  If the only prize is $100, then the biggest prize is $100 and the smallest prize is $100.  You might decide not to report on the least favourite if there's only one movie.  You might decide that if there are two movies both with rating 5, then one is the favourite and the other the least favourite — though choosing which is which is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, exactly what I had in mind. The thing here is to avoid a case of handling unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because you initialize `leastRating` to zero you won't have a least favorite unless the rating is negative.  Not sure that's what you want.

The best suggestion is from @xing, add a include

```
#include <limits.h>
```

and initialize you best and worst like this;

```
favRating = INT_MIN;
leastRating = INT_MAX;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  setting leastRating = 10; fixed it.